# IDE0059 Unnecessary assignment of a value to 'number'

Tags: c#, integer

I got an assignment where I have a few user inputs. My goal is that the user is only allowed to enter an integer. The program works as I want it to, but this message is messing with me.
What is the problem there, and how do I fix it?

```cs
static int Check_input(string input)
{
    bool is_valid = Int32.TryParse(input, out int number);
    if (is_valid)
    {
        number = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        number = 0;
    }

    return (number);
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't make any sense - If you want to get the user's input, why aren't you returning it? If you want an indication on if the input is a valid int, why not return `bool`?

Comment: Its basically just telling you that you are not using the output of `TryParse`, for which you aren't.  I guess maybe you are just validating its an `int`, though its a little strange to see someone using `TryParse` without using the result... Hopefully you aren't calling a `Convert` style method later to do the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelRandall I get that sometimes you don't actually need the `int` value, what's strange here is combining that with the `int` return type -

Comment: @ZoharPeled yeah I agree. My *Spidey Senses* are telling me (and it could be wrong), that the OP is using the value as a bool switch for a downline method that then calls `Convert`.... or the code is just wrong. Either way something seems fishy

Comment: Regarding your edit, yeah, you initially did write poor code, but was a good question. IMHO you shouldn't answer your question by editing it, but adding an answer. It is not against the rules posting answers to your own questions.

Comment: Hi, your recent edit has been rollbacked because it did not follow the Q&A format. Submitting answers to your own questions is not only allowed but encouraged.

Comment: `static int Check_input(string input) => Int32.TryParse(input, out int _) ? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first line of your method `bool is_valid = Int32.TryParse(input, out int number);` you create a new variable `number` and assign a value to it. But you never use this value, because you immediately assign either the value 1 or 0 to it. Actually, you can shorten your code

```cs
static int Check_input(string input)
{
    bool is_valid = Int32.TryParse(input, out _);
    if (is_valid)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here, you discard the out parameter of `TryParse` and only investigate its return value to check which value your method should return.

But actually, you should return a bool value to see whether the user entered a valid number, which would make your method look like this:

```
static bool Check_input(string input)
{
   return Int32.TryParse(input, out _);
}
```

This is even simpler and it is easier to work with a boolean variable then with an integer that might be 1 or 0. Compare this:

```
if(Check_input("test") == 1)
{
   Console.WriteLine("good input");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("bad input");
}
```

with

```
if(Check_input("test"))
{
   Console.WriteLine("good input");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("bad input");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need to asign number with `out int number`, because you are setting it to 0 or 1 later anyway.

To be more accurate your if, else is useless anyway. You are already setting the number to either 1 or 0 or you wouldn't be able to set it equal to a bool anyway.

**Fixed Code:**

```cs
static bool Check_input(string input) {
    bool is_valid = Int32.TryParse(input, out _);
    return (is_valid);
}
```

Comment: This code would not give feedback whenever the input is an integer or not. With `41` as input it would return `41`. With `0` as input it would return `0`... And with `Hello!` as input it would also return `0`

Comment: Yeah my mistake forgot to return is_valid instead of number.